# MultiByteToWideChar terminating output buffer with junk, but reporting no error. Why?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode, visual-studio-2012

While developing a program the other day, I had to convert an ASCII string into a Unicode string. I'm working on Windows with Visual Studio 2012, by the way. I noticed some strange behaviour with the Win32 function `MultiByteToWideChar` which I couldn't sort out. I wrote some test code, below:

```
int main()
{
    /* Create const test string */
    char str[] = "test string";

    /* Create empty wchar_t buffer to hold Unicode form of above string, and initialize (zero) it */
    wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t*) LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, sizeof(wchar_t) * strlen(str));

    /* Convert str to Unicode and store in buffer */
    int result = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, str, strlen(str), buffer, strlen(str));
    if (result == 0)
        printf("GetLastError result: %d\n", GetLastError());

    /* Print MultiByteToWideChar result, str's length, and buffer's length */
    printf_s(
        "MultiByteToWideChar result: %d\n"
        "'str' length: %d\n"
        "'buffer' length: %d\n",
        result, strlen(str), wcslen(buffer));

    /* Create a message box to display the Unicode string */
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer, L"'buffer' contents", MB_OK);

    /* Also write buffer to file, raw */
    FILE *stream = NULL;
    fopen_s(&stream, "c:\\test.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(wchar_t), wcslen(buffer), stream);
    fclose(stream);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it simply takes an ordinary character string, creates a buffer to store the Unicode string in, puts that converted Unicode string into the buffer, and shows me some results, also writing the buffer to a file.

The output:

```
MultiByteToWideChar result: 11
'str' length: 11
'buffer' length: 16
```

Already weird. The function is processing the correct number of characters in the C string, but `wcslen` is reporting the output buffer to be longer than the C string! I'm pretty sure I allocated the buffer correctly, too.

I've tried using different sized string lengths, but there's always junk at the end, and `wcslen` always reports the buffer's length to be a multiple of 4.

Finally, for this particular string (`"test string"`), here's the raw buffer that was printed to file:

```
74 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 73 00 74 00 72 00   t.e.s.t. .s.t.r.
69 00 6E 00 67 00 AB AB AB AB AB AB AB AB EE FE   i.n.g...........
```

(That's 32 bytes, or 16 Unicode characters.)

The 10 bytes at the end are five characters; four [U+ABAB](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/abab/index.htm), and one [U+FEEE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feee/index.htm), which are meaningless to me.

In different amounts, they occur **every time** I try converting a string.

I'm kinda out of ideas. Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to include the trailing null character in the length (pass `strlen(str) + 1` instead of `strlen(str)`). Also your `buffer` is one element too short - it also needs room for the trailing null character.

Comment: @Philipp Wow, that was a lot more basic than I expected. Thanks for such a quick answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/* Create empty wchar_t buffer to hold Unicode form of above string, and initialize (zero) it */
wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t*) LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, sizeof(wchar_t) * strlen(str));
```

This is really where the problem started.  The value of strlen(str) is meaningless, especially so when the input string is encoded in utf-8.  You tend to get away with it by accident because it *usually* creates a buffer that's too long, not counting the off-by-one bug.

But you would also have easily avoided that bug by doing it the Right Way.  You must call the function *twice*.  The first time, pass 0 for the last argument (cchWideChar).  The function returns the required size of the buffer (chars, not bytes).  Which is now good enough to allocate the buffer *and* pass the correct value the second time you call the function.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful technique which I kinda skipped over in the documentation! Thanks!

Comment: Not just useful, it is required.  There's just no other way to guess at the required buffer size.  Albeit that "probably big enough" is not an infrequent choice when dealing with C strings.  Don't do it when you don't have to.

Comment: Actually if you know the encodings then you can calculate a size guaranteed not to be too small. For UTF-8 and UTF-16 counting the number of UTF-8 code units gives an upper limit to the number UTF-16 code units that will be required. It may be larger than necessary (e.g., three UTF-8 code units may correspond to a single UTF-16 code unit) but it will never be smaller than necessary.

Comment: However, the problem is in the code you show; the allocation does not allocate an extra space for the null terminator. In the case of ascii the number of UTF-8 code units will be exactly the number of UTF-16 code units, but strlen does not count the null terminator. The reason the problem is avoided when you call MultiByteToWideChar to determine the correct size is that when you call MultiByteToWideChar with a null pointer as the destination it will (anticipating programers that make this exact mistake) adjust its result to account for the null terminator.

Comment: A simple example blows a gaping hole in that theory.  0x80 is converted to 0xfffd.

Comment: 0x80 is not an ASCII character

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see how that disproves my comments. 0x80 is not a valid UTF-8 encoding, but if you do get this data via some corruption, then as you say it is converted to 0xFFFD; one (invalid) UTF-8 code unit is converted to one UTF-16 code unit. Therefore the number of UTF-8 code units still functions as an upper limit on the number of UTF-16 code units required to store the converted string.

Comment: Sigh, true.  Unicode decomposition usually has a way to bite.  Like Gurmukhi 0xD5 -> 0xF860+0x0A38+0x0A3C in apple's code page.

Comment: wchar_t *tstr = (wchar_t*) LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, sizeof(wchar_t) * s.length() + 1); --- 
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length() +1, tstr, sizeof(wchar_t) * s.length()); --- adding one more unit works for me... people said it is needed for a trailing null termination ... also in the MultiByte* function call s.length() + 1 is needed it seems... anyway... i should have searched SO instead of tingering myself

Answer (score 4):

(Converted comment to answer)

You need to include the trailing null character in the length (pass `strlen(str) + 1` instead of `strlen(str)`). Also your `buffer` is one element too short – it also needs room for the trailing null character.

Comment: Thanks again. Updated `strlen(str)` to `strlen(str) + 1` in all necessary instances.

Comment: This answer is quite wrong, unfortunately.  The buffer's size is just a random value, strlen(str)+1 does not produce an accurate value for the buffer size at all.

Comment: This answer is actually correct. I've commented on Hans Passant's answer with details.

Comment: No.  Quite notable as well how exploitable this is.  An attacker just needs to feed a 0x80 byte to induce a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4):

As others have commented, you are basically misusing `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `wcslen()` by not handling null terminators correctly.  If you don't include the null terminator when calling `MultiByteToWideChar()`, it will not output a null terminator.

Try this instead:

```
int main() 
{ 
    /* Create const test string */ 
    char str[] = "test string"; 
    int strLen = strlen(str);

    WCHAR *buffer = NULL;
    int bufLen = 0;

    /* Calculate buffer size */ 
    int result = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, str, strLen, NULL, 0); 
    if (result > 0)
    {
        /* Create buffer to hold Unicode form of above string */ 
        buffer = (WCHAR*) LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(WCHAR) * (result+1)); 
        if (buffer != NULL)
        { 
            /* Convert str to Unicode and store in buffer */ 
            bufLen = result; 
            result = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, str, strLen+1, buffer, bufLen); 
        }
    }

    if ((!buffer) || (result == 0))
        printf("GetLastError result: %d\n", GetLastError());          

    /* Print MultiByteToWideChar result, str's length, and buffer's length */ 
    printf_s( 
        "MultiByteToWideChar result: %d\n" 
        "'str' length: %d\n" 
        "'buffer' length: %d\n", 
        result, strLen, bufLen); 

    /* Create a message box to display the Unicode string */ 
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer, L"'buffer' contents", MB_OK); 

    /* Also write buffer to file, raw */ 
    FILE *stream = NULL; 
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&stream, "c:\\test.dat", "wb");
    if (err == 0)
    { 
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(WCHAR), bufLen, stream); 
        fclose(stream); 
    }
    else
        printf("Errno result: %d\n", err);

    if (buffer)
        LocalFree(buffer);

    return 0; 
}
```

Since you are using C++, you can simplify the memory management by using `std::string` and `std:wstring` instead

```
int main() 
{ 
    /* Create const test string */ 
    std::string str = "test string"; 
    std::wstring buffer;

    /* Calculate buffer size */ 
    int result = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, str.c_str(), str.length(), NULL, 0); 
    if (result > 0)
    {
        /* Allocate buffer to hold Unicode form of above string */ 
        buffer.resize(result); 

        /* Convert str to Unicode and store in buffer */ 
        result = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, str.c_str(), str.length(), &buffer[0], result); 
    }

    if (result == 0)
        printf("GetLastError result: %d\n", GetLastError());          

    /* Print MultiByteToWideChar result, str's length, and buffer's length */ 
    printf_s( 
        "MultiByteToWideChar result: %d\n" 
        "'str' length: %d\n" 
        "'buffer' length: %d\n", 
        result, str.length(), buffer.length()); 

    /* Create a message box to display the Unicode string */ 
    MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer.c_str(), L"'buffer' contents", MB_OK); 

    /* Also write buffer to file, raw */ 
    FILE *stream = NULL; 
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&stream, "c:\\test.dat", "wb");
    if (err == 0)
    { 
        fwrite(buffer.data(), sizeof(std::wstring::value_type), buffer.length(), stream); 
        fclose(stream); 
    }
    else
        printf("Errno result: %d\n", err);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I usually avoid C++ standard library classes due to the possibility of overhead (and the fact that I like dealing with memory myself if I know what I'm doing [which I guess I sometimes don't!]). I'll consider it though, if I need to do more complex operations.